# Antiderivative of $y = \frac {x+22} {x^{2}+2x-8}$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm taking the AP Calculus BC Exam next week and ran into this problem with no idea how to solve it. Unfortunately, the answer key didn't provide explanations, and I'd really, really appreciate it if someone could explain how to solve this problem - **I'm having trouble with the antiderivative of the curve.** It's a non-calculator question.

> Which of the following is equal to the area of the region bounded by the lines $x = -3$, $x = 1$, $y = 0$, and the curve $y = \dfrac {x+22} {x^{2}+2x-8}$?

a) $\ln 5$

b) $6\ln 5$

c) $7\ln 5$

d) $8\ln 5$

e) $10\ln 5$

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is c. let me explain. the function is negative so we need to find :
$$ -\int f(x)dx  $$
between $(-1 , 3)$.
Note that : $x^2  +2x -8 = (x+4)(x-2)  $
So, $$\frac{x+22}{x^2  +2x -8} =\frac{x+22}{(x+4)(x-2)}   $$
Now $$\frac{x+22}{(x+4)(x-2)} = \frac{A}{x+4} + \frac{B}{x-2}$$
after some calculation you will get that $A = -3$ and $B = 4$.
So we need to find
$$ -\int_{-1}^3 \frac{-3}{x+4} + \frac{4}{x-2}dx  $$
and that equals $$ \Big[ -3\ln(|x+4|) + 4\ln(|x-2|)\Big]_{-1}^3 = 7\ln(5)  $$

Comment: Quick question: After we figure out the values of A and B and set up the integral, why do we ignore the original x + 22 in the denominator? I thought we would have to factor it in somehow.

Comment: because when we figure out A and B both expressions are equivalent. so doing the integral to left side of the equation is like doing integral to the right one, you can check that the right side is equation to the left by going backwards.

Comment: I understand now. thank you so much! :]

Comment: your welcome :)

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

As $x^2+2x-8=(x+4)(x-2)$

use [Partial Fraction Decomposition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartialFractionDecomposition.html),

$$\dfrac{x+22}{x^2+2x-8}=\dfrac A{x+4}+\dfrac B{x-2}$$